# How to modify an element inside a String[] which is inside an Arraylist inside another Arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

So I have two Arraylists bBag representing a bigBag and sbag1 and sbag2 representing smaller bags. sbag1 and sbag2 are Arraylist containing String[] and both of them are inside bBag.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;

public class Arraylist1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<ArrayList<String[]>> bBag = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String[]>>();
        ArrayList<String[]> sbag1 = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        ArrayList<String[]> sbag2 = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        String[] s1 = {"this", "is" , "Java", "bruh"};
        String[] s2 = {"It", "rained"};

        sbag1.add(s1);
        sbag1.add(s2);

        String[] s3 = {"today", "is", "20"};

        sbag2.add(s3);

        bBag.add(sbag1);
        bBag.add(sbag2);



    }
```

I want to modify sbag2's 1st string (i.e Today) to 'Tomorrow'such that it gets replaced in the bBag as well. Also how do i display it? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable, so you cannot directly modify it, you must replace it with a new string. Your containers, arrays and arraylist, hold references to objects in memory, not copies of object data. So, if you change the array, that change will be visible to any arraylist holding the array, and arraylist holding that arraylist, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Only way is to traverse from bBag to bBag1 to s3 and update it. Do the same traversal to display from bBag.

Answer (score 0):

This might work, but you need to replace the String with the new one.

```
public void modify(int bag, int sbag, Integer pos, String replacement){
    //with bag being 1 or 2
    //with sbag being 1 or 2
    bBag.get(bag-1).get(sbag-1)[pos]= replacement;
}
```